# How can I check for daily updates for Ubuntu 16.04 via command line?

Tags: bash, command-line

I do not know how to check for this via command line.  I do know that you can do this for through the GUI; however, I want to implement this in my script.  Anyone know how to do this? (I haven't found anything about this).

Comment: `sudo apt update` will check for available updates.

Comment: This question looks better suited for [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). There are existing posts there that seem related, like [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/457874/727997) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/49958/727997).

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu updates are managed through the [apt](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/apt.html.en) package manager.

If you're looking to run daily updates you'll want to do something like:

```
sudo apt update # updates apt packages index
sudo apt upgrade # runs upgrades on all packages
```